# modify chrome extension and don't destroy the extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

After modifying a chrome extension‘js code and restart the chrome，the modified chrome extension becomes destroyed.
Three months ago,i did the same thing to the same extension and it worked well.

This time i get a new computer and the lastest version chrome(46.0.2490.86 m),but once i modify the extension's source code it get destroyed.

Here is the source code and the extension.
PS:i think it's because chrome refuse me to modify its origin extension code.

extension name：totop.
extension function：Add a back to top button and go to bottom button on every page

i just modify "500" to "100" to accelerate its speed.

the main script.js:

```
 $("head").prepend("<style>._BackToTopPlus{width:35px;height:35px;border-radius:5px; position:fixed; right:10px; cursor:pointer; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:50% 50%; background-color:#000; opacity:.1;transition:opacity .2s ease-in-out;z-index:99999;}._BackToTopPlus:hover{opacity:.5}</style>");
var level=$(window).height()/2-50;
$("body").append("<div class='_BackToTopPlus' style='background-image:url(data:img/png;base64,R0lGODlhEgAUAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAASABQAAAImjI+py+IPo4xmWmRpyq5dFkzgoY3VY5KS9ykcKy6vnMEr3W417hQAOw==);top:"+(level-40)+"px;'></div>").append("<div class='_BackToTopPlus' style='background-image:url(data:img/png;base64,R0lGODlhEgAUAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAASABQAAAIqlB2peX27nINKNsoswnrTLmABKJKcJH5PGl3siKZdabZgWN2rzuPv/yoAADs=);top:"+(level+5)+"px;'></div>");
var jsq=0;
$("._BackToTopPlus").eq(0).click(function(){$("body").animate({scrollTop:0},500);}).mouseover(function(){
    jsq=setInterval(function(){
        $("body").scrollTop($("body").scrollTop()-1);
    },20);
}).mouseout(function(){clearInterval(jsq);jsq=null;});
$("._BackToTopPlus").eq(1).click(function(){$("body").animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()},500);}).mouseover(function(){
    jsq=setInterval(function(){
        $("body").scrollTop($("body").scrollTop()+1);
    },20);
}).mouseout(function(){clearInterval(jsq);jsq=null;});
```

Comment: maybe related ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657617/how-to-disable-google-chrome-extension-autoupdate

Comment: Try changing `chrome://flags/#extension-content-verification` flag to `bootstrap` although it will reduce the overall security of extensions so there's no guarantee Chrome will respect your setting, see https://crbug.com/443867

Comment: @wOxxOm, thank you very much. it is chrome default settings that cause my trouble. The path you proposed is ver nice. PS:me me da.(づ￣3￣)づ╭❤～

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### spend 1 years, i myself get the answer !

chrome browser will auto detect all its extension online to guarantee safety, so after editing one extension file, chrome browser will report error on the extension.

### solution

1. copy all extension files out, edit files what we need, delete other irrelevant files, modify manifest.json.
2. start chrome develop mode
3. load the extension

### example

#### old extension files include

- _locales
- _metadata
- jq.js
- logo.png
- manifest.json
- script.js

#### new extension files

files we need is:

- jq.js
- logo.png
- manifest.json
- script.js

edit sript.js to get function we need.
edit manifest.json, mine manifest.json like:

```

```
{
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "jq.js", "script.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
   } ],
   "icons": {
      "128": "logo.png"
   },
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "ToTop",
   "version": "1.0.0.0"
}
```

```