# Are unpacked Chrome extensions automatically updated?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to use an old version of Evernote Web Clipper and prevent the browser from updating it, so I extracted the .crx and loaded it as an unpacked extension. Can Chrome automatically update extension installed this way?

Comment: AFAIK no, but you can edit manfest.json and remove `update_url` just in case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, chrome would not auto-update the unpacked extension(that is in developer mode). Whenever you load an unpacked extension, you get a unique `app id` which will be different from the one that is hosted on chrome web store or any other server. The `update manifest` returned by the server, which is the xml document required for updates, references this `app id` which would now be different. Therefore updates will not happen. To read up more on how updates happen in chrome, you can refer this link in the documentation https://developer.chrome.com/apps/autoupdate.