# How to disable Google Chrome extension autoupdate in 2020+

Tags: google-chrome

How do I prevent a specific extension from auto-updating itself?

(The old and now-locked answer "How to disable Google Chrome extension autoupdate" does not work anymore)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Google Chrome extension autoupdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657617/how-to-disable-google-chrome-extension-autoupdate)

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the folder it is in.  e.g. click the chrome 3-dots, then "more tools" => "Extensions", and long gibberish code it gives, then search your disk for that folder name in your file system.
2. Copy that folder to a different place on your hard drive (e.g. click on the folder, then Ctrl-C, then open your "Documents" folder, then Ctrl-V
3. Uninstall the extension.  You need to get rid of the one that will auto-update first.
4. Load the version you copied: e.g. click the chrome 3-dots, then "more tools" => "Extensions" and click the "load unpacked" button.

Comment: e.g.: dir \pnlccmojcmeohlpggmfnbbiapasdliob /s/w/a works on windows to find roboform

Comment: Your Q&A belongs to SuperUser, not StackOverflow...

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't aware of the changes - I just posted to the same place as the original out-of-date (now locked) location https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657617/how-to-disable-google-chrome-extension-autoupdate

Comment: Uh... so you're knowingly posting a duplicate?

Comment: If you consider a new answer that works in 2020 a "duplicate" of a broken answer on a locked post from years ago that no longer works, then yes - I'm posting a duplicate.  If there's a way to un-lock the old post and update the answer - go ahead - I couldn't work that out.

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore, or at least not for me.

Comment: The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657617/how-to-disable-google-chrome-extension-autoupdate) you linked is now unlocked.