# Disable Chrome browser extension autoupdate on Pixel Chromebook

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, chromebook

Is it possible to disable autoupdates for the Chrome browser on Google Pixelbook chromebooks? This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657617/how-to-disable-google-chrome-extension-autoupdate) describes the procedure for Windows, Mac OS, and Ubuntu for Chromium. But I'd like to disable Chrome browser extension autoupdates on my Pixelbook.

Comment: ChromeOS [supports](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#ExtensionSettings) policies so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67698984) in the linked topic should work after some adjustments.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll give it a shot. I don't have Chrome Enterprise, though.